# python split characters of a string by chunks

Tags: python, string, slice

I want to split the string `s = "123456789"` into `["123","234","345","456","567",..]`  or `["12","23","34","45","56",...]` as per chunk size.

I tried out the following :

```
from textwrap import wrap
s = '1234567890'
print(type(wrap(s, 3)))
```

The result was `["123","456","789","0"]`  but not ["123","234","345","456",..]

How to get what I want? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
s = "123456789"
max_len_of_each_item = 3
length = len(s)

print([s[i:i+max_len_of_each_item] for i in range(length-max_len_of_each_item+1)])
```

Same code in a function kinda type

```py
def wrap(_string_variable, _max_len_of_each_item):
  length = len(s)
  temp = length-max_len_of_each_item+1

  return [_string_variable[i:i+_max_len_of_each_item] for i in range(temp)]

s = "123456789"
max_len_of_each_item = 3

print(wrap(s, max_len_of_each_item))
```

Outputs:

```
['123', '234', '345', '456', '567', '678', '789']
```

Tell me if its not working...

Answer (score 0):

use `more_itertools` library and `windowed` function

https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.windowed